# How to know the device's microSD card reader specifications?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, file-system, file-transfer

In my opinion, for clarity and transparency before purchasing a device, it would be necessary that manufacturers clearly indicate on the data sheets of their devices more information about the device specifications:

- The type of compatible microSD cards (Ex: SDHC / SDXC / ...)
- The type of supported file systems. (FAT32 / exFAT / ...)
- The maximum theoretical capacity of supported microSD card (Up to 32GB/ UP to 2TB /...)
- The class of the card reader, to know the maximum speed of compatible cards (Classe 10: Min Write Speed: 10 MB/s 25 MB/s....)

How to get this information without relying on manufacturer declarations?

Comment: Not sure if that's a good question for this site – but the usual answer would be [GSMArena](http://gsmarena.com/).

Comment: First two points are covered [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170359/131553) and also see the link at the end of answer. For the other two points what is published is perhaps the only way, as Izzy suggested